# C# Minimal API Middleware de reintentos con Polly

Tags: api, c#-8.0, middleware

Estoy haciendo una minimal API en C# .NET 8 y quiero agregar un Middleware con logica de reintentos usando Polly, pero no estou pudiendo hacer que funcione correctamente.

Esta es mi politica de reintentos:

```
var retryPolicy = HttpPolicyExtensions.HandleTransientHttpError()
                                      .WaitAndRetryAsync(3, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(retryAttempt));
```

Pero no estoy pudiendo crear el Middleware que detecte el error y si lo hubo que vuelva a intentar la misma petición.

Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Como estas realizando tu configuración para usar esta política (retryPolicy(?